# Restify Put method

Tags: node.js, restify

I try to use the PUT but keep getting 404 error
**ResourceNotFoundError : product/1 does not exist**
I'm pretty new to this, so I don't know exactly where I go wrong. Please help me out, thank in advance.

server.js

```
var restify = require('restify');
var mongojs = require('mongojs');

var db = mongojs('mongodb://xxxxxx', ['products']);

var server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

server.get("/products", function(req, res, next) {
    db.products.find(function(err, products) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }); 
        res.end(JSON.stringify(products));
    });
    return next();
});

server.post("/product", function(req, res, next) {
    var product = req.params;
    db.products.save(product, function(err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        });
        res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
    return next();
});

server.put("/product:id", function(req, res, next) {
    db.products.findOne({
        id: req.params.id
    }, function(err, data) {
        //merge req.params/product with the server/product

        var updProd = {};
        //logc similar to jquery.extend();
        for(var n in data) {
            updProd[n] = data[n];
        }
        for(var m in req.params) {
            updProd[m] = req.params[m];
        }

        db.products.update({
            id: req.params.id
        }, updProd, {
            multi: false
        }, function(err, data) {
            res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            });
            res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    });
    return next();
});

server.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started @ 3000");
});

module.exports = server;
```

client.js

```
var restify = require('restify');
var server = require('./server');

var client = restify.createJsonClient({
    url : 'http://localhost:3000'
});

var testProduct = {
    id: "1",
    name: "Apple iPad AIR",
    os: "iOS 7, upgradable to iOS 7.1",
    chipset: "Apple A7",
    cpu: "Dual-core 1.3 GHz Cyclone (ARM v8-based)",
    gpu: "PowerVR G6430 (quad-core graphics)",
    sensors: "Accelerometer, sgyro, compass",
    colors: "Space Gray, Silver"
};

client.post('/product', testProduct, function (err, req, res, product) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Create error ocurred >>>>>>");
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Create product >>>>>>>');
        console.log(product);
    }
});

testProduct.price = "1000";
client.put('/product/' + testProduct.id, testProduct, function (err, req, res, status) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Update error ocurred >>>>>>");
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Update product >>>>>>>');
        console.log(status);
    }
});

client.get('/products', function (err, req, res, products) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("An error ocurred >>>>>>");
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Total products " + products.length);
        console.log('All products >>>>>>>');
        console.log(products);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the line in `server.js` to read `/product/:id` .  You left out a `/`.

Comment: Aww. Did not notice that. Thank you.